# Select all posts that user hasn't responded to?

Tags: mysql

I have a website that shows posts, and a user can vote on it. After they vote once I don't want it to show to that user again. So I need to have a query that polls all posts and returns the ones the user has not yet responded to.

I was thinking it would be simplest to have a posts table, responses table, and user table. The response table could include a postId, and userId. This could allow me to see all the posts that a user *has* responded to, but I couldn't figure out how to flip it to show the negation. Also it seems like it would be pretty slow to do it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all posts which have *not* yet been seen by a given user, you could try the following query:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM responses r
                  WHERE r.postId = p.postId AND r.userId = <some value>)
```

As an alternative to using `NOT EXISTS`, you could also phrase this using a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN responses r
    ON p.postId = r.postId AND
       r.userId = <some value>
WHERE r.postId IS NULL
```

Comment: That seems to work just fine, can't say I would have come up with that, thanks!

EDIT: Is either version preferable? I image the left join has a bit of a speed advantage

Comment: @DasBeasto Actually, `NOT EXISTS` might be the fastest way. If you had proper indices setup on `responses`, the left join might be almost as fast.  Really, just choose the version you find more comfortable.